# Flutter RawMaterialButton won't get transparent

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this simple `CircularButtonWithIcon`. The one problem is that it won't respect transparency when no color is setted.

```
class CircularButtonWithIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  CircularButtonWithIcon({
    Key key,
    @required this.onPress,
    this.padding,
    this.border,
    this.active = false,
    this.marginRight,
    this.marginLeft,
    this.icon,
    this.color,
    this.activeColor,
    this.text,
    this.splashColor,
    this.image,
    this.hasState,
    this.borderColor,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final double padding;
  final double border;
  final double marginRight;
  final double marginLeft;
  final Icon icon;
  final Image image;
  final Color color;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color borderColor;
  final Widget text;
  final Color splashColor;
  final Function onPress;
  final bool active;
  final bool hasState;

  @override
  _CircularButtonWithIconState createState() => _CircularButtonWithIconState();
}

class _CircularButtonWithIconState extends State<CircularButtonWithIcon> {
  bool active;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    active = widget.active;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FittedBox(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: widget.marginLeft ?? 0, right: widget.marginRight ?? 0),
        child: RawMaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              active = !active;    // don't use widget.active
            });
            if (widget.onPress != null) widget.onPress();
          },
          fillColor: active
              ? widget.activeColor ?? widget.color ?? Colors.transparent
              : widget.color ?? Colors.transparent,
          splashColor: widget.splashColor ?? Colors.grey,
          child: widget.text != null
              ? Container(
            child: widget.text,
          )
              : widget.image ?? widget.icon,
          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          padding: widget.padding != null ? EdgeInsets.all(widget.padding) : EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          shape: CircleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
                width: widget.border ?? 2.0,
                style: BorderStyle.solid,
                color: widget.borderColor ?? Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Take a look at:

```
        fillColor: active
                  ? widget.activeColor ?? widget.color ?? Colors.transparent
                  : widget.color ?? Colors.transparent,
```

When no color is seted, it should be transparent.

I did this:

```
                  CircularButtonWithIcon(
                      padding: 10,
                      border: 3,
                      onPress: () => {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.remove,
                          color: Color.green,
                          size: 60))
```

and it's getting a color background instead of merging:

[image]

however it looks like it's just the background but darker. Is it possible that the button is adding a shadow on top of the background color? How can I remove it? I looked at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RawMaterialButton-class.html and couldn't find anything related to shadow effects on the button

Comment: `body: Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.all(64),
decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
child: RawMaterialButton(
onPressed: () => print('onPressed'),
child: SizedBox.expand(),
),
),` works just fine

Comment: @pskink but what if I must add a color? How can I deactivate the color based on a boolean? I gotta use transparent in some cases

Comment: `elevation: 0.0`

Comment: @pskink works, thanks